# IIS Virtual Directory based on a Server Variable?

Tags: environment-variables, iis-10, virtual-directory, server-variables

**Is there a way to set a virtual directory path based on some server side variable?**

We have a production and staging web farm as well as development and regression web servers:  7 total.

I want all production web servers to use a virtual directory which points to a production file share.
Likewise, the staging web server's virtual directory would point to the staging file share.
etc...

I would like to avoid making a code change for this -- unless someone has a better idea.

Windows Server 2016 Standard
IIS v10.0.14393

Thank you

Comment: Can you do something with a symbolic link to the share?  Not sure if IIS lets you use a symbolic link as a virtual directory so only a comment but I know you can use a symbolic link in handler mappings.

Comment: interesting.  I've never heard of MKLINK before.  I'

Comment: Instead of all such hacks, set up all your stages as separate sites (or virtual directories) and then a reverse proxy in front to forward the traffic to wherever you like, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: If you want to automate the creation of the website, you could refer to the IIS Appcmd.exe for creating a virtual directory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771804(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
I recommend that you use Azure DevOps to continuously build and deploy applications to production and development environments.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops